# How to compile console.log("1") with asc in AssemblyScript?

Tags: typescript, console.log, assemblyscript

I want to compile in *AssemblyScript (TypeScript)* a code that shows a *1*, using `console.log`.

My file called **example.ts** contains the following:

```js
console.log("1")
```

I compile it as follows:

```sh
asc example.ts
```

But I get the following error:

```sh
ERROR TS2304: Cannot find name 'console'.

 console.log("1")
 ~~~~~~~
 in example.ts(1,1)

FAILURE 1 compile error(s)
```

The same thing happens with `process.stdout.write("1")`.

How is this solved?

Answer (score 1):

I asked for help on *AssemblyScript server on Discord* and a contributor *(dcodeIO)* was able to fix a bug about *UTF-8 encoding*. So for this it is necessary to have *AssemblyScript as of version 0.17.7*, the version in which this error was fixed. Also, another collaborator *(MaxGraey)*, helped me to create the codes, and also to install the packages.

First you have to install the loader:

```sh
npm i @assemblyscript/loader
```

In my case I couldn't, I had to install it globally, due to reading problems on the USB where I have the operating system installed:

```sh
npm install --force -g @assemblyscript/loader
```

You have to be careful, there is an `npm` package called `assemblyscript-loader`, notice that it has a minus sign in the center, you don't have to do the following:

```sh
npm install --force -g assemblyscript-loader # Do not do it, it is wrong.
```

The code of **example.ts** has to be as follows:

```
namespace console {
    declare function log(str: string): void;
}

/*
  main generally unnecessary if you don't use
   the `import` object on the host side,
   but in this case it's better to delay the implicit
   initialization during module instantiation
*/
export function main(): void {
    console.log("1");
}
```

To compile the **example.ts** with `asc`, you can do the following ... I add optimizations for less file weight:

```sh
asc -O3z --converge -b ./example.wasm ./example.ts
```

This generates a file of *3033 bytes*, equivalently to *3 kb*.

To execute the **wasm** code from *Node.js* you have to create a file, for example, **example.js**, and it would look like the following:

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const loader = require('@assemblyscript/loader/umd');

loader.instantiate( fs.readFileSync("./example.wasm"), {
    example: { // if your file called "example.ts"
        "console.log"(ptr) {
            console.log(exports.__getString(ptr));
        }
    }
})
.then(module => {
    exports = module.exports;

    exports.main(); // call entry point
})
.catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
})
```

It is important to use `fs.readFileSync("./example.wasm")`, since when using only `"./example.wasm"`, it does not work. This is because the implementation of the *loader AssemblyScript* (which is created in *Node.js*), in the **index.js** file approximately on *line 333*, asks as an argument a variable of type `Buffer`, which are the bytes of the **example.wasm**.

In my case, as I install it globally, in the **example.js** I changed it to the following:

```js
const loader = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/@assemblyscript/loader/umd');
```

To run the **example.js** file from *Node.js*, it can be done as follows. I put code tracing arguments in case something strange happens:

```sh
node --trace-warnings --track-heap-objects ./example.js
```

The output of running the command is as follows:

```sh
1
```

As you can see, it works correctly.